PC won't sleep while PS5 controller is plugged in
My Windows 11 PC won't go to sleep or turn off the screen automatically when while I have my Playstation 5 controller plugged in via USB. The PC will only sleep if I either manually put my PC to sleep sleep from the start menu or unplug my controller. Restarting my PC doesn't resolve the issue, even if I stay on the lock screen before logging in.
Running powercfg -requests list no processes preventing sleep.

Looking at Device Manager, I found four devices that are added when I plug in the PS5 controller via USB. (It's possible I may have missed some). There is no Power Management tab when checking the properties of these devices.

Audio inputs and outputs > Headset Microphone (2-Wireless Controller)
Audio inputs and outputs > Speakers (2- Wireless Controller)
Human Interface Devices > HID-compliant game controller
Sound, video and game controllers > Wireless Controller

Connecting and disconnecting the controller while USBLogView is open shows three devices with the following information.

How do I get my PC go to sleep while a PS5 controller is plugged in?

Can you put your system to sleep manually with the controller plugged in?

@Ramhound Yes, manually activating sleep mode works.

Does the machine wake up with interaction from the controller?

Check Power Options, e.g., wake timers, selective USB suspend, multimedia settings.

I had this issue when keeping a PowerA Fusion 3 (third-party wired USB Xbox controller) plugged in to my Windows 10 computer prevented the screen from turning off, even with nircmd monitor off. Unfortunately the official PowerA app bricked that controller during a firmware update, so I got a new first-party Microsoft Xbox Wireless controller (the Series X/S generation) which doesn't exhibit this problem when plugged in over USB. I haven't had this issue with my DS4 either, not sure how different the DualSense is.

Can you post a screenshot of the properties for the device?  I would think it's some sort of power setting..  If i go to device manager and get properties for my keyboard device, there's a power management tab that has options like "allow the computer to turn off this device to save power" and "allow this device to wake the computer".  I think if similar options are available to you, using them might resolve the problem.

Can you, manually, put it to sleep, when the controller is connected?

@Netan I can manually put the PC to sleep, yes.

@apocalysque I see an HID-compliant game controller listed. Unsure if the PS5 controller has any other entries in device manager.

Then try to turn the remote off, to see if the device is getting disconnected in Device Manager
